# Editing static control both statically and dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I've got a static control in ASP.NET - a regular old `<ul>` on a master page. On some of the content pages I add to this `<ul>` statically by just inserting `<li>` statically in the content placeholder, but on one of the others I'd like to add dynamically on the server side, e.g. an `<li>` for each file in a directory. How can I achieve both these objectives? When I add `runat="server"` it still doesn't seem to have a server-side representation I can modify.

Comment: The ul tag could be in the head of a repeater. Then you wouldn't even need to access the ul/li tags. Have you tried that?

Comment: By the way, what's the reason to do this directly in a master page? I would recommend making a `ContentPlaceHolder` on the page so you have easy access to it. You could then make a user control and just databind to that from your pages.

Comment: I did make a ContentPlaceHolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a loop in the template directly, instead of some C# code-behind.